# Нужен ли веб-сервер для локального запуска приложения?

Tags: веб-сервер

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, нужен ли веб-сервер для запуска и функционирования своего веб-приложения на своем локальном компьютере? Если нет, то кто же отвечает на http запросы во время пользования веб-приложением?

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем точно вы выразились. Хотя бы сказали, на чем веб проект писать собрались?

Если сайт, который строится на php, или используется javascript, то сервер понадобится обязательно. Сойдет [denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/). Просто для html/css сервер не нужен.

Если же какой-то язык программирования конкретный (не скриптовый), то обычно используется сервер написанный на том же языке. Для java приложений, например, используется Tomcat, Netty и т.д. Без сервера полноценное веб приложение не получится использовать.
Уточняйте вопрос.

Comment: Планирую писать приложение на питоновском фреймворке django или flask

Comment: @user203111 оба имеют встроенный веб-сервер

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, нет, необязателен. Если приложение состоит из набора статических страниц, оно вполне может загружаться по URL с протоколом `file` без веб-сервера — для таких браузер сам обратится к файловой системе средствами ОС. Это уже, формально, не HTTP. А из-за неприятных уязвимостей, связанных с этой возможностью браузеров, некоторые действия на страницах по URL с таким протоколом заблокированы.

Но вы же хотите серверную часть, которая будет отвечать по HTTP? Значит, веб-сервер вам всё равно потребуется; но обычно где есть веб-фреймворк, там же есть и реализация простенького вебсервера и в любом руководстве по фреймворку будет написано, как его запустить.

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваш сайт написано на серверном языке программирования, то, безусловно, Вам нужен локальный веб-сервер. Например, Denwer или OpenServer

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?